# iOS App crashing when 'false' connection is available

Tags: ios, crash, wifi, reachability, sttwitter

I am developing an app that allows the user to view the public twitter feed using the the STTwitter Library (see below code)

```
    STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI  twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"**consumer  key**"
                                                         consumerSecret:@"**consumer  secret**"];

    [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"screenName"
                              successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
                                  NSLog(@"-- statuses: %@", statuses);


                                  self.statuses = statuses;

                                  [spinner stopAnimating];

                                  [self.tableView reloadData];



                              } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {



                              }];

 } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Network Access"    message:@"Please Try Later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     NSLog(@"No Network");

 }];
```

When i turn the wifi off on my laptop, the app enters the error block and all is well, the user is presented with an alert saying that a connection is not available.

However as i am using a wifi hotspot (e.g. bt openzone), which requires a login, when i turn the wifi back on and do not log in (meaning i cannot access the internet), the app thinks it has access to the internet and attempts to access the twitter api and crashes.

I've tried using 'Reachability' to try to establish weather or not the internet is available (see below)

```
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
    NSLog(@"There IS NO internet connection");
} else {

    NSLog(@"There IS internet connection");

}
```

However this did not work.

Will apple reject my app for something like this?

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Thanks for any help :)

**EDIT**

```
2014-01-22 08:58:02.268 SWIP[384:a0b] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2014-01-22 08:58:02.268 SWIP[384:a0b] ***INTERNET AVAILABLE****
2014-01-22 08:58:11.090 SWIP[384:a0b] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2014-01-22 08:58:11.091 SWIP[384:a0b] ***INTERNET AVAILABLE****
2014-01-22 08:58:17.295 SWIP[384:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0xbc47e00> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class  is not key value coding-compliant for the key token_type.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x029205e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x026a38b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x029b06a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x023648ca -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)   valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x022d1921 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 81
5   Foundation                          0x022d0f5b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)   valueForKey:] + 260
6   SWIP                                0x0000375f __65-[STTwitterAppOnly   verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:]_block_invoke + 191
7   SWIP                                0x00005e8d __109-[STTwitterAppOnly   postResource:baseURLString:parameters:useBasicAuth:progressBlock:successBlock:errorBlock:]_block_invoke156 + 173
8   SWIP                                0x00037231 __121+[STHTTPRequest(STTwitter)   twitterRequestWithURLString:stTwitterProgressBlock:stTwitterSuccessBlock:stTwitterErrorBlock:] _block_invoke48 + 449
9   SWIP                                0x00046255 -[STHTTPRequest  connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 517
10  Foundation                          0x0246db59  ___NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading_block_invoke + 40
11  Foundation                          0x024043e1 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 62
12  Foundation                          0x0228ca6e -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 119
13  Foundation                          0x0228c9d6 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 208
14  Foundation                          0x0228c8e8 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 76
15  Foundation                          0x0228cc98 _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading +    43
16  CFNetwork                           0x00c78e6f ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 111
17  CFNetwork                           0x00c76bac ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 104
18  CFNetwork                           0x00cc10ef ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 25
19  CoreFoundation                      0x028c1d59 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
20  CFNetwork                           0x00be05af _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv   + 139
21  CFNetwork                           0x00cc16d2   _ZThn16_N19RunloopBlockContext24multiplexerClientPerformEv + 20
22  CFNetwork                           0x00be03dd _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv +  299
23  CFNetwork                           0x00be01f2 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv    + 76
24  CoreFoundation                      0x028a983f   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
25  CoreFoundation                      0x028a91cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
26  CoreFoundation                      0x028c629e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
27  CoreFoundation                      0x028c5ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
28  CoreFoundation                      0x028c58db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
29  GraphicsServices                    0x0345c9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
30  GraphicsServices                    0x0345c809 GSEventRun + 104
31  UIKit                               0x01411d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
32  SWIP                                0x0000670d main + 141
33  libdyld.dylib                       0x031b2725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: STTwitter library should not crash on network condition changes.

It you post the crash stack trace we'll be able to tell you what to fix.

Comment: @nst please see stack trace. Thanks

Comment: I confirm that this is a crash in the STTwitter library. I just pushed a fix: https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/commit/54efe271cfc562bad246d08362cda2f221132871 please let me know if you encounter any further issue.

Comment: Excellent! Works fine now :) You should submit that as an answer and ill accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that this is a crash in the STTwitter library.

I just pushed a fix: https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/commit/54efe271cfc562bad246d08362cda2f221132871

Please let me know if you encounter any further issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Will apple reject my app for something like this?
```

Well, it probably won't, but it should. You are proving an application that is crashing and you know about it. As for the wifihotspot, I find it hard to believe that you cannot do it using reachability, as that piece of code appears in numerous places.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195717/491239), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2665967/491239) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4709862/491239).

You can do another test, instead of the above solutions:

```
[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname: @"http://www.google.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do not intend to submit as is. As for the posts, i've seen and tried them and all occur the same problem.